# In angular2 if a route doesnt exist I want the user directed to the homepage

Tags: angular

In angular2 if a route doesnt exist I want the user directed to the homepage

I'm using the latest angular2 and typescript.

Do I add this code to the app routes file somewhere?

**This is my routes file: - how would i update this file to do that:**

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeRoutes } from './components/home/index';
import { ContactRoutes } from './components/contact/index';

export const routes: Routes = [
...HomeRoutes,
...ContactRoutes    
];
```

**This is my homepage routes:**

```
import { Route } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './index';

export const HomeRoutes: Route[] = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'homepage',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    component: PageNotFoundComponent 
  }
];
```

Answer (score 3):

This is done in your module when setting the routes. Note the route with the '**' path. You can set that to whatever component you like.

See: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: 'hero/:id', component: HeroDetailComponent },
      { path: 'crisis-center', component: CrisisListComponent },
      {
        path: 'heroes',
        component: HeroListComponent,
        data: {
          title: 'Heroes List'
        }
      },
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
      { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
    ])
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeroListComponent,
    HeroDetailComponent,
    CrisisListComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Comment: I've added my routes file in my question, how would I update that?

Comment: Also whats PageNotFoundComponent ? like whats in it?

Comment: @AngularM `PageNotFoundComponent` can be any component that belongs to your application.  In your case you'll want to replace it with `HomeComponent` if you want nonexistent paths to redirect there.

Comment: I did that, this then stopped my other routes from working eg contact route

Comment: Is it the last route in the list?